# PHP date difference is a year too short?

Tags: php, datetime

I have this function to give people a little cake icon to celebrate the number of years they've been registered, but it seems to give 1 year too short a time?

```
public function cake_day($reg_date, $username)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $date1->setTimestamp($reg_date);
    
    $date2 = new DateTime();
    
    $cake_icon = '';
    if ($date1->format('d-m') === $date2->format('d-m')) 
    {
        // calculate how many years
        $total_years = $date1->diff($date2)->format('%y');
        if ($total_years > 0)
        {
            $cake_icon = '<img src="/templates/default/images/cake.png" alt="'.$total_years.' years" class="tooltip-top" title="'.$username.' has been here for '.$total_years.' years" />';
        }
    }
    return $cake_icon;
}
```

Example dates:

```
Registered - 19 February 2022 at 8:55 pm UTC (as a timestamp 1645304121)
Today - 19 February 2024 at 11:22 am UTC
```

It ends up only saying it has been 1 year.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Time deltas are always problematic, especially involving Februar and the last days of months. You're essentially beholden to however the underlying API decides to calculate it. Just subtract the two absolute year values (2024 - 2022 = 2).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, simple solution ey. Thanks.

Comment: Does it return two years on/after 8:55PM UTC?

Comment: If you expand the original data format you'll see why it didn't produce the expected result: https://3v4l.org/aJUO3

Comment: You're still a few hours short of the 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a *rounding* issue: at 11:22AM, the user has only been registered for 1 year, 364 days, and a few hours. You want to display "how many years, to the nearest day", but PHP has no way to know that.

One way to solve that would be to truncate each of the timestamps you're comparing to midnight, *then* compare them.

Note that using `DateTimeImmutable`, where each modification creates a new object rather than modifying the current one, is often clearer. Also, instead of `->format('%y')` you can access the `->y` property on the difference to get an integer number of years.

I've also renamed the variables, because I strongly believe that names like `$date1` and `$date2` lead to bugs, because the logic is too hard to read at a glance.

```
$registrationDateTime = new DateTimeImmutable('19 February 2022 8:55 pm UTC');
$now = new DateTimeImmutable('19 February 2024 11:22 am UTC');

$registrationDateOnly = $registrationDateTime->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);
$today = $now->setTime(0, 0, 0, 0);

$totalYears = $registrationDateOnly->diff($today)->y;

var_dump($totalYears);  // int(2)
```